# Ruby Package Include Problems

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm trying to use the [Optiflag](http://optiflag.rubyforge.org/discussion.html) package in my Ruby code and whenever I try to do the necessary `require optiflag.rb`, my program fails with the standard `no such file to load -- optiflag` message. I added the directory with that library to my $PATH variable, but it's still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it a gem? Are you doing

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'optiflag'
```

or equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a gem, so you need to enable ruby gems before requiring it.

[This site](http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70) explains many ways of how to do it. But to have the cheat sheet here these are:

1) Require the rubygems package before using a gem.

```
require "rubygems"
require "optiflag" # etc
```

2) Add the -rubygems flag to wherever you execute ruby. I.e:

```
ruby -rubygems Something.rb
```

3) Add an environment variable called RUBYOPT, giving it an option of rubygems. I.e:

```
RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

Answer (score 0):

I also keep having this problem with RubyXL, tried to use single and double quotes. Is there something else that needs to be done? Maybe putting a file somewhere? I already succesfully installed the gem with sudo gem install rubyXL (RubyXL actually din't work).